# Why my learning curve doesn't make sense when I compute XGBoost?

Tags: python, linear-regression, xgboost

I work on a regression problem with tabular data and around 2000 rows.

After data standardization, skewness modification, outliers removal and hyperparameter tuning, my XGBoost model gives me decent results (I guess?) : r2 score is 0,86 on training set, and 0,85 on test set.

Now, I would like to have clues about the number of data necesseray to achieve good performance. So I chose to plot learning curve.

By using LinearRegression() as an estimator in learning_curve function, this is the kind of plot I obtain.

[Learning curve for linear regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG6AM.png)

Seems legit.

Now I process the same way for XGBoost. As hyperparameters, I feed my XGB regressor with the ones the hyperparamter tuning found (Full code is avalaible at the end of the post). And I end up having this plot :

[Learning curve for XGBoost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr1hg.png)

Validation score doesn't make sense : it should decrease from 1 to somewhere auround 0,85... I get the exact same evolution if I use another scoring method (‘neg_mean_squared_error’ for example).

I don't think my code is wrong, it has more to deal with my understanding of the whole process. Any hint?

Finally, here is the code :

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

train_sizes = [1, 2, 3, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500, 800, 1100, 1400]
features = ['Product Quantity', 'Departure SLP', 'Departure TMP', 'Departure W/C', 'Departure AGE', 'Travel Time', 'Outside Temp at Load Time', 'Humidity at Load Time']
target = 'Arrival SLP'

xgr =XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
             colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=0.9697304149116983,
             gamma=2.684899398839369, gpu_id=-1, importance_type='gain',
             interaction_constraints='', learning_rate=0.2595302873251097,
             max_delta_step=0, max_depth=29,
             min_child_weight=33.522965527801304,
             monotone_constraints='()', n_estimators=24, n_jobs=8,
             num_parallel_tree=1, random_state=0, reg_alpha=1.8409864324165623,
             reg_lambda=6.009121364172622, scale_pos_weight=1,
             subsample=0.8948522801808735, tree_method='exact',
             validate_parameters=1, verbosity=None)

train_sizes, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator = xgr,
    X = loads_df[features],
    y = loads_df[target], train_sizes = train_sizes, cv = 5,
    scoring = 'r2',
    shuffle=True)

train_scores_mean =train_scores.mean(axis = 1)
validation_scores_mean =validation_scores.mean(axis = 1)
print('Mean training scores\n\n', pd.Series(train_scores_mean, index = train_sizes))
print('\n', '-' * 20)
print('\nMean validation scores\n\n',pd.Series(validation_scores_mean, index = train_sizes))

plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, label = 'Training error')
plt.plot(train_sizes, validation_scores_mean, label = 'Validation error')
plt.ylabel('r2 score', fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel('Training set size', fontsize = 14)
plt.title('Learning curves for XGBoost', fontsize = 18, y = 1.03)
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(0,1)
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Did you choose your learning rate to be `1.8409864324165623`, or is that a different parameter?

Comment: Also, `0.2595302873251097` is still a heavy learning rate. Try lowering it down -- a lot.

Comment: My learning rate is 0.2595302873251097 and my alpha regularization is 1.8409864324165623. Those values come from my random hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: Those values give me the best results. During tuning, I tried learning rate ranging from 0.0001 to 0.4.

Comment: Honestly, both of those curves look suspicious. How come at least one of those values always starts at zero?

Comment: Can you post `learning_curve`?

Comment: It doesn't start at zero, plot is cropped at the bottom (ie r2 value for a training set size of 1 is -8.3).
learning_curve is already included in the code bloc in the original post.

Comment: Oh its a proprietary `sklearn` function. I thought it's your own.